# php for loop working on each itiration

Tags: php

the following code should return only "5" once (for first ittiration) 
instead returning "5" for each iteration. AS "5555555555555555555555555"

```
$col11=5;

for($x=1; $x<=5; $x++) {
   for($y=1; $y<=5; $y++) {
      if("$col{$x}{$y}") {
           echo $col11;
        }

   }
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What do you expect of this line `if("$col{$x}{$y}")`?

Comment: if col11 exists it should display its value

Comment: instead the value is being displayed for clo12,clo 13 and so on. But they dont exist

Comment: Why are you storing values in separate variables when they are a good fit for an array? That will solve all your issues

Comment: This seems like a bad way of doing things, using arrays like others have suggested is much more common and for a good reason.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, indent your code if you want others to read it, please.

Comment: Also seems fairly pointless as your echo always puts out the fixed value anyway - `echo $col11;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` condition is simply checking whether the string provided is a truthy value. Yeah, you are interpolating the `$x` and `$y` values but it's still just a string. What you can do is put together the name of the variable as a string, then use `$$` to access the variable name dynamically. You can also use `isset()` to determine if the variable has been set.

```
<?php
$col11=5;

for($x=1; $x<=5; $x++){
    for($y=1; $y<=5; $y++){

        // Store desired variable-name as string in a temp variable
        $variable = "col{$x}{$y}";

        // Check this temp variable's existance by using referece variable ($$)
        if (isset($$variable)) {
            echo $$variable;
        }

    }
}
?>
```

[Check Output here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ba128144f0748c2a33aacb5ab833c9e9ccebd4f)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `if` condition like this:

```
$col11=5;

for($x=1; $x<=5; $x++){
    for($y=1; $y<=5; $y++){
        $val = "col{$x}{$y}";
        if($$val) 
        {
          echo $col11;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I just changed my answer. Please check @ZahidJabbar

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand when you want to echo $col11 ? Maybe you want to echo col for x=1 and y=1 so you can make this condition :

```
if ($x==1 && $y==1)
```

I'm not sure what you research ?

Comment: You are checking if a string exist that you manually typed in. It will always be true.